# pushing div up inside container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to push a div up inside a container. I set a margin of `500px` from the top and it pushes down every other div inside the container with it. I have included two photos of what I am getting and how I want it to look. Also I have included the code.

This is how it should look this is my photoshop rendering of the completed website
[image: Proper]

This is what it looks like now I am just working on laying out the colored boxes. The `background image` is a gradient set in the `body` of the page. The `header` should be the white part in the above image with the buttons,picture and login tabs. The `core` should be the area directly below the `header` with the small white line towards the right. The `bottomOutsideBox` should be the light gray box that is directly below the gradient on the outside and next to the `core` it should be positioned `500px` below the top of page since the `header` is set to `500px` from the top. The small green gap at the top of the image is just a sliver there is `500px` of green above it because when I set the `margin-top:500px` it pushed everything down with it. I want the `header` to stay at the top then have `core` directly below it and `bottomOutsideBox` on the outside of `core`. I have the `bottomOutsideBox` set to black in the picture so its easier to distinguish.
[image: not good]

```
/*gradient*/

body {
background-image:url('../Images/gradient.gif');
background-color:#000000;
}

header {
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:block;
}

div#bottomoutsidebox {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 500px;
    width: auto;
}

/* page core */
div#core {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #dadbd6;
    width: 750px;
    height: 250px;
    clear: both;
}

img.mainLogo {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>testing</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to my basic template.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="bottomoutsidebox">
        <header>
            <img class="mainLogo" src="Images/logo.jpg"/>
        </header>

        <div id="core">

        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>Some copyright and legal notices here. Maybe use the © symbol a bit.</p>
        </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the markup that I'd suggest for this type of layout, use a container class to center your content and change the background based on sections, since you only need two different backgrounds then the header will be the only section you need.

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qnj3q/1/embedded/result/)**

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img class="mainLogo" src="Images/logo.jpg" />
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="core"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}
.container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    background: lime;
}
header .container {
    height: 500px;
    background: #fff;
}
#core {
    height: 250px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```